# Error when trying to use pubnub

Tags: codenameone, pubnub

Good day all, I've been developing an office chat app in which i plan on using the Codename one Pubnub lib, but whenever i try launching the app via the simulator i get this error: "Error:(1044, 23) java: cannot access org.json.JSONArray class file for org.json.JSONArray not found". And i didn't make use of JSON in my code. Really don't.
I have tried deleting and redownloading the JSON lib, still no positive result.
All my libs are up to date. A little direction on what to do will be appreciated. Thanks all

Comment: Share your code here. **We are not code writing service**

Comment: Which version of PubNub SDK are you using? How are you managing your dependencies? gradle, maven, manual adding jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pubnub library has a dependency on their version of the JSON lib and you need to install that by its side for things to function. Notice this isn't our version of the JSON library but a specific version for pubnub.

Comment: Thanks sir, please how do I include their version of JSON in my app?

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master_3x/codenameone you need to place it in your lib directory.